Forwarding a Telegram photo album
I'm trying to make a bot that will accept a message from a user (it can be just text, photo with text, photo, album, album with text), but I'm running into the problem that I can't forward an album. I am using telebot. Thanks in advance
I don't know how such a thing can be implemented(

What is your question? Have a look at how to ask
